# How to include clickable link in VisualStudio QuickInfo

Tags: vb.net, documentation, editor, visual-studio-2017

If I hover over a method name in VisualStudio a  [**QuickInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/137ey1yz(v=vs.100).aspx) is shown as a ToolTip, e.g.

[image]

I would like to be able to click on the link that I included in the quick info. Here is my corresponding method comment:

```
    ''' <summary>       
    ''' Copy the schema of the input table with the given name.
    ''' <para>
    ''' See https://svn-extern.isi.fraunhofer.de/projects/forecast4/wiki/CopySchema
    ''' </para>
    ''' </summary>
```

In VisualStudio2017 I am able to click on the ToolTip (does not work in VisualStudio2012) but the hyperlink is not active. I would expect that I could use some xml tag in the method comment to activate the hyperlink but I did not find one that works:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11082/c-and-xml-source-code-documentation

A tag "a", simlar to the one in the article above

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

does not work for me. Does the html support for QuickInfos need to be enabled somehow in the VisualStudio settings?

Currently, I can jump to the method declaration and then Ctrl+Click on the hyperlink in the method comment. However, I would prefer to directly click on the url in the QuickInfo.

Is there any way to do so, e.g. with an xml tag that I missed or with Resharper or another VisualStudio extension?

Comment: Something like this in R#? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html (Ctrl-Shift-F1 or CTRL-Q, depending on your keybinding)

Comment: Yes, that works. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Would be great If I could use the Quick Documentation instead of the QuickInfo as default (but as ToolTip and not as sticky Popup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper can do this with its [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html) feature.

To invoke use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, depending on your keyboard scheme.

There is also the [Enhanced Tooltip](https://github.com/MrJul/ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip) extension, which improves Tooltip formatting, but also doesn't support clickable URLs (sources available though, you could try to add it yourself).